# Magento 1.9.3 Error: user has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30)

Tags: magento-1.9

Can somebody help me please to see if there is any solution for this error.
We are getting it a few times, especially when we are trying to make changes to some of the products or add new products.
So far the solutions I found on the internet and tried had to do with changing the Max Users Connections in the database which I can't do, I got "access denied", and the Webhosting company said we can't, as we are on a Shared Hosting.
We also can't access the Apache folder.
Anybody has any suggestions?
Thanks heaps

Comment: You need to increase the server resources, if not allow, you can change your web host.